# Perfomance and Stabilty questions are appropriated here?

Tags: discussion

I'm pretty new to Programmers.SE and was thinking about if here is appropriate to ask for example something like.

> Is Node.JS ready for stay in production environment?

Or even something that is what I really would like to know

> Is Sails.Js (a node.js framework) ready for production and with good performance ?

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Thanks @gnat. Do you see a way to fix it up to make it appropriate? Considering not the recomendation but the expertise got from experience?

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) referred in prior comment? (in particular, there's a section titled "Is there a place where I can ask such questions?" that you might find helpful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everybody has a different opinion of:

> Production ready...

and...

> Good performance

This would be closed as Primarily Opinion Based.  It will attract a large number of discussions and low quality answers.  Voting will be done based on popularity and not necessarily objective facts.

You might want to look at our Software Recommendations beta site for StackExchange.  You might have better luck there.